# how to use php files from other domain name?

Tags: php, webserver, include-path

using two portals with different web domains (Eg: www.buyer.com, www.seller.com), i have a common php file in ***www.buyer.com*** i need to include that file  ***www seller.com*** how it is possible.

the file login

> www.buyer.com/main/login.php

that have a code

```
    if(user_flag == "seller")
{
    include("www.seller.com/system/login_cfm.php");
}
else
{
    include("../system/login_cfm.php");
}
```

but its not working what to do...

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you tell me what the value of `allow_url_include` is in your php.ini file?

Comment: changing the flag to one is a security issue

Comment: you should have a look first on the documentation http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php. Are your portals source files on the same server?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't copy the file onto the second server?

Comment: yes sir,the case is in seller login from the buyer page at the time the validation moved to the buyer domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check php.ini for following option. it should be true.
 allow_url_include boolean
    This option allows the use of URL-aware fopen wrappers with the following functions: include, include_once, require, require_once.

Check source link : http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: This will not work if the files aren't accessible on the same server, as the OP is likely confusing a PHP file and the web-facing file generated by his webserver.